# Angular GRPC API call using Envoy proxy

Tags: angular, grpc, envoyproxy

I am not able to hit GRPC server from the ui via envoy.
Here is the Envoy proxy code:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8888
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                  grpc: {}
                route:
                  cluster: backend_grpc_service
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: backend_grpc_service
    connect_timeout: 0.250s
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    typed_extension_protocol_options:
      envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
        explicit_http_config:
          http2_protocol_options: {}
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: backend_grpc_service
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 0.0.0.0
                port_value: 50051
```

code in angular module using grpc web client:

```
GrpcWebClientModule.forRoot({
      settings: { host: 'http://0.0.0.0:8888' },
    }),
```

used this commend to generate ts proto files from python proto files:

```
"proto:generate": "protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ng=$(which protoc-gen-ng) --ng_out=./src/protos -I ../ensuing/protos/ $(find ../ensuing/protos -iname \"*.proto\")"
```

The issue is that UI is able to hit envoy but returns 404 as it is not able to hit grpc server deployed locally in a docker container at port 50051.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the full example here
https://github.com/alexcpn/grpc-web-angularjs-2022

Documented here https://medium.com/better-software/interface-grpc-with-web-using-grpc-web-and-envoy-possibly-the-best-way-forward-3ae9671af67 in details

The server project is here https://github.com/alexcpn/go_grpc_2022.

Copy the Protos of the service we need to call here in another folder

We are adding it here -`proj/src/app/search/interfaces/microservice1/test.proto`

Then we need to add the compile directive for protoc and protoc-gen-ts to generate the necessary client files in the package.json file

```
"compile": "./node_modules/protoc/protoc/bin/protoc  --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:src/app/search/proto  --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcweb:src/app/search/proto -I ./src/app/search/interfaces/ ./src/app/search/interfaces/**/*.proto",
```

Pre-requisite : you need to install these plug-ins as pre-requisite

```
npm install google-protobuf protoc ts-protoc-gen
npm i --save-dev @types/google-protobuf
npm install grpc-web
```

Compile with npm `test-proj$ npm run compile`

After that we use the generated client files as shown in our service - test-proj/src/app/search.service.ts

Please check the repo and documentation for more details